# How do I add a picture to this if command.

Tags: javascript

How do I add a picture to this if command, i want to add a picture of a charizard `if computerChoice < 0.10`:

```
if (computerChoice < 0.10) {  

    computerChoice = confirm("Charizard");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript confirm/ alert boxes are text only!. If you need picture to be displayed you need to use a modal dialog like [jquery modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to display pictures. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/o4uoprnu/

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information.
    <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/130th-anniversary-of-france-delivering-the-statue-of-liberty-to-the-united-states-5635375607316480-res.png"></p>
</div>
```